# jQuery dynamic accordion function

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, jquery

Having a problem with using a function in my dynamic accordion divs.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "accordion-query.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
            {
            var accord='';

            $.each( data, function( index, item)
                {
                var courseCode = item.Course_Code;
                accord += '<h3>'+item.Course_Name+' - '+item.Course_Code+'</h3><div>'+createTable(courseCode)+'</div>';
                });

            $( "#accordion" ).html( accord );
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
            }
    });
});
```

The `createTable(code) {}` function inside the accordion divs is not working
function createTable(code)

```
function createTable(code) 
    {
    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "staff-query.php",
        data: "q=" + code,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
            {           
            $.each( data, function( index, item)
                {
                tabletext += '<tr><td>'+item.B_Code+'</td><td>'+item.Surname+', '+item.FirstName+'</td><td>'+item.Email+'</td><td>'+item.Course_Name+'</td><td>'+item.Mod_Title+'</td><td>'+item.Title+'</td><td>'+item.Uploaded+'</td><td>'+item.ViewedDate+'</td><td>'+item.Comments+'</td></tr>';
                });
            }
    return tabletext;
    });
    }
```

The `accordion-query.php` and `staff-query.php` are both returning what i want them to, json encoded arrays with the correct data in them, but it wont pass through to the table.
When I change the function to something simple like...

```
function createTable(code) 
    {
    return code;
    }
```

...it puts the correct data into the div and displays all the accordion tabs properly.  I cannot see the issue with the function.  The `document.ready {}` and the `createTable()` are both in the header, I have tried moving them to after the body and all other combinations.  I havent shown the `<table><tr><th>` opening and closing tags so as not to clutter up the code, but that is not the problem either as I have tried and tested it.